# how to connect API file in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have created file api.php in config folder and connect it to the main php file.

First of all it says

```
'require(/config/api.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\myproject\resources\views\main.blade.php)'
```

API options

```
$options = [
    'limit'=>10,
    'offset'=>2,
    'domain'=>$_POST['texter'],
  ];
```

It says 'Notice: Undefined index: texter in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\myproject\config\api.php on line 10'

Answer (score 0):

You could access to config variables using `config()` method.

```php
$some = config('api.some');
```

[Configuration - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/configuration)